Why it Kotlin's Set implementation mutable under the hood?
I just noticed something interesting about Kotlin's Set data structure and its interaction with Java.
Consider a List object first.  If I have this code in Kotlin:
private val aList = listOf(1,2,3)
fun giveMeAList() = aList

fun printAList() = println(aList)

and this in Java:
List<Integer> aList = TestKotlin.INSTANCE.giveMeAList();
TestKotlin.INSTANCE.printAList(); // [1,2,3]
aList.add(4); // UnsupportedOperationException
TestKotlin.INSTANCE.printAList();

I get an UnsupportedOperationException at the .add.  This is expected because under the hood it's an (immutable) List.  But because it fulfills the List interface and Java doesn't have the concept of immutable collections, the compiler doesn't detect this and it fails at runtime.
But now consider the identical Kotlin code, except replace List with Set types.  Then this Java code:
Set<Integer> aSet = TestKotlin.INSTANCE.giveMeASet();
TestKotlin.INSTANCE.printASet(); // (1, 2, 3)
aSet.add(4); // no exception thrown
TestKotlin.INSTANCE.printASet(); // (1, 2, 3, 4)


No exception is thrown.  Just like List's, Kotlin differentiates between mutable and immutable Set's.  In Kotlin there is no aSet.add.  Why do sets not exhibit the same behavior?   Is this intentional?  Is this something that may not be changed under the hood in a future version of Kotlin?

How does giveMeASet look like?

private val aSet = setOf(1,2,3) and then fun giveMeASet() = aSet.  I thought that was obvious so I thought it better to not clutter the question.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73548084/casting-list-to-mutablelist-in-kotlin-fails-at-runtime-in-jvm

Yes, this is something that may change under the hood.
In general, Kotlin tries not to reinvent data structure implementations for the JVM, instead preferring to use built-in java.util data structures.  For listOf, it might make sense to use Arrays.asList, which doesn't support add; for sets, there isn't really anything better than LinkedHashSet.
This is generally perfectly normal for Kotlin; it certainly doesn't guarantee that its collections cannot be modified, it only guarantees that their public API available from the Kotlin language doesn't support mutation.

Kotlin’s standard library doesn’t have the concept of immutable collection interfaces either. Set, List, and Map are read-only, not immutable. This means they can be read-only windows to mutable data.
If you want truly immutable collection interfaces, there is an official Kotlin library for that: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.collections.immutable

That philosophy sounds contrary to the fact that Kotlin named the different types "List" vs "MutableList", with the implication that the first one is "immutable".

That implication was never correct.  Note, for example, that MutableList is a subtype of List.

@J-bob The fact that MutableList is a subtype of List logically demands that List cannot be assumed mutable. The existence of MutableList therefore does the opposite of implying that List is immutable.
